# How to select specific first child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div id="divL">
  <br><br>
  <div id="person">abc</div>
  <div id="person">xxx</div>
  <div id="person">xxx</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#divL:first-child div{
    background:#ffffff;  //doesn't work
}
```

I want to jump over `<br>` tags and select the first `div` tag (`abc)` inside `divL`

Comment: Solved, thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:first-of-type` instead.  The `<br>` is selected by `:first-child`

```
#divL div:first-of-type
```

Also note that you want to select the first div that is a child of `#divL`, not `#divL` that is a first child.

By the way `id`s should be unique.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) instead:

```
#divL div:first-of-type {
    background:#000;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CYh5G/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
    #divL> div:first-of-type { 
   background:#ffffff; 
    }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3GWZ9/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
div#divL div:first-child {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#divL > div:first-of-type {
    background:#ffffff;  
}
```